# Convert list of tags into a tag cloud in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, tags

After much hacking about I am using the following code to generate a list of tags being used for the current category within a custom post type called 'Review'...

```
<?php
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
query_posts('post_type=review&posts_per_page=-1&cat='.$cat_id);
 if (have_posts()) :
 $posttags = array();
 while (have_posts()) : the_post();
   if( get_the_tag_list() ){
   $posttags = array_merge( $posttags, explode('||', get_the_tag_list('','||','')));
   }
 endwhile;
 $posttags = array_unique( $posttags );
 sort($posttags); //sort optional
   if( $posttags ) { 
    echo '<ul><li>';
   echo implode("</li>\n<li>", $posttags);
   echo '</li></ul>';
   }
 endif; wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

This works correctly and outputs the correct list, but I want to turn this list into a tag cloud, can anyone help?

Comment: See [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud) for relevant wordpress function and example php usage.

Comment: Yeah i've been through all of that, I am trying to convert the list that I have already generated into a tag cloud.  I'm not sure that function will allow me to do that, or am i wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to use your list?

Comment: Because i've been unable to generate a tag cloud that just returns results from the 'review' custom post type

Comment: A tag only exists for _one_ post type. If you create a new taxonomy, you have to say, for example, this is for reviews. So if you generate a tag cloud for a certain tag that belongs to the review post type, no other post type can affect that. So you _can_ use wp_tag_cloud...

Comment: And BTW if you want to build your own tag cloud function you should start by studying wp_tag_cloud in the WP source code. It will show you how to compile a list of tags the right way... you could copy that code and modify it as needed.

Comment: Rather use `pre_get_posts` or `WP_Query` for your queries. You should never use `query_posts`, it is a sin. Wish wordpress decides in the very near future to depreciate `query_posts`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud
```

Or else go with some plugins,

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-tag-cloud-widget/
```

Hope this helps you